# Value Doesn't Change on API Post Request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

**SOLVED UPDATE**: The fee value is autogenerated by the API based on the location of the delivery, so I can't update or change it manually.

---

So I am using this api and when I add a custom value for the order_value option it updates automatically. However, when I try to change the fee, it doesn't change the value and shows a fixed number every time.

Is there a reason is shows the fee in a yellow color text? (on nodemon) while the other options are in green? Because even the order value is in yellow, but I am able to update that using my form inputs on my front end. Only the fee of 975 seems to not change and I think it might be a default calculation from the API?

[image]

In my express server this is what i put for my code

```
{
     order_value: req.body.item1,
        fee: req.body.item1,
      },
```

And my html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="10" onClick="updatePrice()">
    <label for="item1">12 piece wings $10</label>
</div>
```

So basically you can see it has a value of 10 so hence when I submit my form the order value changes to 10, however, the fee is still 975??

Here's a link to the official [API docs](https://developer.doordash.com/en-US/api/drive#operation/CreateDelivery)

I couldn't see any info regarding how the fee is determined or if I can manually update it

Comment: "Is there a reason is shows the fee in a yellow color text? (on nodemon)?". yes, it is because the value is a number and the other fields are strings and your console shows them in different colors

Comment: ah okay, but what would explain the fee value being a fixed number? because I didn't type that number anywhere and it seems I cannot change it